# Get data from XML in simple way

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I am using the following code to get data from the OData XML and its works ,
but I am not sure that I fully understand it so maybe there is a way to write it in simple way?
what i need is to get the property value which is in the first loop value = 0001 and text = approve and in the 
second value = 0002 text = reject

**The code**

```
XNamespace dns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
      if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
         string decisionOptions = ReadResponse(response);
         XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(decisionOptions);
         foreach (XElement element in document.Element(dns + "DecisionOptions").Elements(dns + "element"))
        {
            PropertyKeyRef decisionOption = new PropertyKeyRef();
            decisionOption.PropertyValue = element.Element(dns + "DecisionKey").Value;
            decisionOption.PropertyName = element.Element(dns + "DecisionText").Value;
             dat.Add(decisionOption);

        }
      }
```

**the XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <d:DecisionOptions xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
- <d:element m:type="TAS.DecisionOption">
  <d:InstanceID>007</d:InstanceID> 
  <d:DecisionKey>0001</d:DecisionKey> 
  <d:DecisionText>Approve</d:DecisionText> 
  <d:CommentMandatory>false</d:CommentMandatory> 
  <d:Nature>POSITIVE</d:Nature> 
  </d:element>
- <d:element m:type="TAS.DecisionOption">
  <d:InstanceID>007</d:InstanceID> 
  <d:DecisionKey>0002</d:DecisionKey> 
  <d:DecisionText>Reject</d:DecisionText> 
  <d:CommentMandatory>true</d:CommentMandatory> 
  <d:Nature>NEGATIVE</d:Nature> 
  </d:element>
  </d:DecisionOptions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here how can do it in  simple way  using LINQ

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
            XNamespace dns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
            //in xml every element should have it's namespace for this reason  I have to concatenate namespace with the name of element  
            var elementsRes = xdoc.Root.Elements(dns+"element").Select((elt) => new PropertyKeyRef { PropertyName = elt.Element(dns+"DecisionKey").Value.ToString(),PropertyValue = elt.Element(dns+"DecisionText").Value.ToString() }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in elementsRes)
            {
                //your code for the result  
            }


        }
    }
    public  class PropertyKeyRef
    {
        public string PropertyName
        { get; set;  }
        public string PropertyValue
        { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer its works!can you please explain briefly how you did it ?what is the elt for example and how can i know when I can use such of logic.

Comment: elt  it's pointer for the current element in  iteration  what you have written in Linq will have an equivalent in code when the IL code is generated  something like  this  private static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectIterator<T, TResult>(
                              IEnumerable<T> source,
                              Func<T, TResult> projection)
   {
      foreach (T item in source)
         yield return projection(item);
   }

Answer (score 1):

You have already achieved it in simplest way. Little bit of `LINQ` might improve readability (get away with foreach loop) but it's just `syntactic sugar` of what you have written.

```
XNamespace dns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("database.xml");

PropertyKeyRef decisionOption = new PropertyKeyRef();
decisionOption.PropertyValue = document.Descendants(dns + "DecisionKey")
                                   .Select(node => node.Value).First();
decisionOption.PropertyName = document.Descendants(dns + "DecisionText")
                                   .Select(node => node.Value).First();

dat.Add(decisionOption);
```

Comment: thanks foryour anser,when i tried your code I got error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string' any idea how to resolve it.I have tried with IEnumerable<String> .but there is another way to make it work with the propertyRefKey

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check. `Select` returns `IEnumerable<String>` but you need only first item so use `First()` after that.

Comment: Thanks but in this case I need the loop also since Im getting in the decisionKey just 0001 and I need also 0002...

Comment: Then you can loop over `IEnumerable<string>` and create objects. Isn't it working that way?

Comment: Or you can do it the way Julie has suggested. But in the end it will going to breakdown to foreach loop only after compiling. Like i mentioned its just syntactic sugar.